# Putting the date in descending order using SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I am having issue with putting the date on the chart as screenshot shown. My database has both 2017 and 2018 data. But when i preview the report, it shows only 2018 and the month has jumbled up too. I added screenshot for more information.

[image]
[image]

Note : I am using Visual Studio 2017 with SSRS.

Thanks.

Comment: This is because the months have been sorted into alphabetic order. Add an extra column for the month using a CASE statement. e.g. 1 = January, 2 = February etc. Sort your data by the numeric month value but display the alpha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dataset, either include a set of numbers for sorting your months (Jan = 1, Feb = 2, etc) or simply provide a `date` value on which to group, such as the first of each month.

By using a `date` value, you are free to treat the value as a date within the report and use all the date formatting functions available within SSRS to present the chart how you require.

For example, if had `2018-01-01` against all your `Jan-2018` data, you can simply group by the `date` for the chart axis which will sort correctly, then use the `=format(Fields!YourDateValue.Value,"MMM yyyy")` expression (change as required) to return an appropriately formatted axis label.

If you really want to have the Year grouping on your axis labels, change the grouping expression to `=year(Fields!YourDateValue.Value)`.

Comment: I tried using =format(Fields!YourDateValue.Value,"MMM yyyy") and it works. But now the graph shows this than monthly basis. 

https://imgur.com/a/AYDsJ

Comment: That is because you have provided the actual date, rather than just the first of the month for each data point.  If you are using a TSQL query you can use `dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,YourDateCol),0)` and if you absolutely need to do this in your report (not recommended), group on `=date(year(Fields!YourDateValue.Value),month(Fields!YourDateValue.Value),1)` or `=Fields!YourDateValue.Value.AddDays(1-day(Fields!YourDateValue.Value))`

Comment: Yes. My date data in the db is the actual date like `yy-mm-dd`. 

How to check whether i am using TSQL? I tried on the codes you provided and it could not verify it.

Comment: If you are using a SQL Server database and a SQL script as your dataset source, then you are using TSQL.